# how to get connect => in neovim and terminal(alacritty) with nerd font

Tags: neovim, alacritty

I recently customized neovim with watching youtube video, and I saw connected => sign and am using same nerd font as well but it doesn't appear on my terminal and neovim.
best regards,
pls answer my questions

I tried changing fonts and switching terminal.

Comment: Alacritty does not support ligatures: https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/issues/50. In order to have this feature you need 1) font with ligatures such as Fira Code 2) terminal that supports ligatures e.g. Windows Terminal or iTerm2.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a programming/stack exchange question. There are other exchange sites, forums or that yt video comment section that might be a better place for this. Poweruser or unix exchange.

What you are looking for are called 'ligatures', are you sure you added and installed [patched nerd font](https://www.nerdfonts.com/)? Also not all terminals support ligature see [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278175/do-any-open-source-linux-terminals-and-fonts-support-ligatures) on unix exchange for a few. I recommend [kitty](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/). the fonts and kitty should be available from your distro repo on linux.